# Pass parameters to shell script stored in HDFS

Tags: bash, shell, hadoop, hdfs

I want to execute a shell script stored in HDFS with an option of passing parameters to the script. I've verified the following works

`hadoop fs -cat hdfs://path_to_script/sample.sh | exec bash`

I want to make the following work

`hadoop fs -cat hdfs://path_to_script/sample.sh param1 param2 param3 param4 | exec bash`

The issue is that the cat command expects files to be streamed to stdout but the parameters are folders and files stored in HDFS. Any other way of making it work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try something like the following; it uses a separate invocation of `hadoop fs cat` (in a process substitution) to retrieve each file and present it to `sample.sh` as a file name to open for reading.

```
# Adjust the hdfs: URLs as necessary
hadoop fs -cat hdfs://path_to_script/sample.sh | exec bash  \
  <(hadoop fs -cat hdfs://param1) \
  <(hadoop fs -cat hdfs://param2) \
  <(hadoop fs -cat hdfs://param3) \
  <(hadoop fs -cat hdfs://param4)
```

If `sample.sh` already knows that how to read from hdfs, then

```
hadoop fs -cat hdfs://path_to_script/sample.sh | exec bash -s param1 param2 param3 param4
```

may be sufficient. The `-s` option tells bash to read the script from standard input, so that it doesn't mistake `param1` as the name of the script to run.

Comment: Thank you chepner , the option with -s worked and now i'm able to pass parameters to the script

Answer (score 0):

You can try with:

```
hadoop fs -cat hdfs://path_to_script/sample.sh | exec bash -s param1 param2 param3 param4
```

Answer (score 0):

This will execute shell script which is in HDFS

```
 hdfs dfs -cat /user/gno1kor/HiveSqoop/HivequeryToWrite.sh | exec bash -s param1, param2
```